# How to uncache error.stack in V8?

Tags: node.js, v8

It appears that after the first time the [`Error.prepareStackTrace`](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API#customizing-stack-traces) is used, the output of the `error.stack` is cached:

```
try {
  null();
} catch (error) {
  Error.prepareStackTrace = () => {
    return 'Hello, World!';
  };

  console.log('#0', error.stack);

  Error.prepareStackTrace = () => {
    return 'Hello, Stack Trace!';
  };

  console.log('#1', error.stack);
}
```

Current output:

```
#0 Hello, World!
#1 Hello, World!
```

Expected output:

```
#0 Hello, World!
#1 Hello, Stack Trace!
```

How to uncache the `error.stack` value to allow further use of `Error. prepareStackTrace`? Without this, I have no guarantee that by the time I have instance of `error`, someone else hasn't already dumped the stack.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible. The caching process is at a level lower than even `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, and from JS code is literally transparent.

Comment: You can use "prepareStackTrace()" only once. Calling it twice will not change anything. Here's some [docs](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API#customizing-stack-traces) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var getStackTrace;

Error.prepareStackTrace = () => {
  return { toString: () => getStackTrace() };
};

var exception;
try {
  null();
} catch (e) {
  exception = e;
}

getStackTrace = () => "Hello World.";
console.log(exception.stack);
getStackTrace = () => "Hello Stack Trace.";
console.log(exception.stack);
```